# NSDateFormatter not working properly with UTC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have the following date:   2011-04-29T14:54:00-04:00

When it runs through the following code to convert it to a date, the date is null for some reason:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
[dateFormatter release];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Any help would be appreciated

SOLVED:

Ok, I figured it out.  For some reason, this method doesn't work.

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
```

This works instead.  Hope it helps someone!

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDate *date = nil;
[dateFormatter getObjectValue:&date forString:localDate range:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Which is null? The string that you try to log at the end, or the date you get from the first date formatter? Also, your second format seems weird: are you really trying to get "four digit year - minutes - day"?

Comment: The date variable is nil when I stop at a breakpoint on the NSLog line.  I just put that four digit year - minutes - day as a test to write it back as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. For some reason, this method doesn't work.

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
```

This works instead. Hope it helps someone!

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDate *date = nil;
[dateFormatter getObjectValue:&date forString:localDate range:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: do you know how to to add that timeoffset "2012-10-15T09:46:16+02:00" so to get "2012-10-15 11:46:16"? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the timezone:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

and you might need to quote the -'s, :'s, and the Z in your format string (maybe not the -'s and :'s, but I think at least the Z):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
```

Other than those, that is how my date formatter is configured and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter seems to only implement the canonical formats for timezones with 'Z' as described in [UTS #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns). With [no leniency in parsing](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Lenient_Parsing).

1. TimeZoneID+/-offset with hours and minutes separated by colon, eg. 2011-04-29T14:54:00GMT-04:00
2. +/-offset with no separation between hours and minutes, eg. 2011-04-29T14:54:00-0400

Try changing the format of the timezone in your localDate string.